# How to change the 'tooltipicon' of 'notifyicon' in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, notifications

How to add my own icon?

```
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000, "Message", "The File has been successfully uploaded!!", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

Comment: [Can I use a custom icon in a BalloonTip?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c4605cc6-4ffa-4b1b-9c06-aaaecdec8ee8/solved-can-i-use-a-custom-icon-in-a-balloontip?forum=vbgeneral) • [ToolTip With Image C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42050/ToolTip-With-Image-C)

Comment: `new Icon(path)` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Icon__ctor_System_String_

Comment: @RandRandom The parameter doesn't take a normal icon like that.

Comment: @OlivierRogier The link is for Visual Basic

Comment: @HiSura That's the same thing in C# but I don't know if the solution is valid and works.